# ActionLink Error When The Function Uses BEANs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am getting the following error.

> "Sorry - An error occurred while processing your request."

I am trying to add a simple ActionLink to go back to a list of categories.

The code in view is:

```
<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Return to List of DVDs", "DVDs", 
                         New With {.controller = "DVD"})%>
</p>
```

The code in my function is:

```
        Function DVDs(ByVal category As Integer) As ActionResult    
        Dim DVDsList As IList(Of DVDBEAN) = _DVDSearchService.GetDVDs(category)
        If Not User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account")
        Else
            If Not User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
                Return View("CustomerDVDs", DVDsList)
            End If
            Return View("DVDs", DVDsList)
        End If
       End Function
```

I am new to web development and ASP.NET so go easy on me. I appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p><%: Html.ActionLink("Return to List of DVDs", "DVDs", "DVD")%></p>
```

Comment: I've tried that and I'm getting the same error.

The URL I'm trying to get back to is: 

http://localhost:49638/DVD/DVDs?category=1

But instead the ActionLink takes me back to:

http://localhost:49638/DVD/DVDs